# Space in value part of RewriteMap

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, apache2

This question is related to [Apache RewriteMap with URLs containing space doesn't work](https://serverfault.com/questions/806103/apache-rewritemap-with-urls-containing-space-doesnt-work), but in this case the issue is a space in the *value* part of the map, not the *key* part. Say I have this entry:

```
/a-normal-url/    /a-less-normal url/
```

As a `RewriteMap`'s [`txt`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html#txt) files are space separated, this won't work as-is. I've thus tried to escape the space:

```
/a-normal-url/    /a-less-normal%20url/
```

Unfortunately `mod_rewrite` will helpfully escape the redirect target, so this will lead to the request being redirected to `/a-less-norma%2520url/`, which also isn't what I want.

Just in case, I've also used a backslash to escape the space (`/a-less-normal\ url/`), but unsurprisingly this also didn't help (it will redirect to (`/a-less-normal%5c`) in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually realized what the answer was when writing the question (classic case of rubber duck debugging).

Just add the `NE` flag in the `RewriteRule` that actually uses the rewrite map's output, somewhere along these lines:

```
# Define the RewriteMap
RewriteMap redirect_map "txt:redirect_map.txt"

# Look up the requested URI in the redirect map. If the result is not empty...
RewriteCond ${redirect_map:%{REQUEST_URI}} ^(.+)$

# ...then use the mapped value for the redirect, without percent-encoding it
RewriteRule . %1  [R=301,L,NE]
```