Apache2 + php-fpm + DocumentRoot with spaces = AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'
We're running a server with Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS with multiple versions of php via ppa:ondrej/php.
A few weeks ago, some of the virtual hosts stopped working (Apache2 fails with "AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'").
Pinning down the problem, we found out, that only virtual hosts which DocumentRoot contain spaces fail.
In a scenario with two document roots at /var/www/directory/ and /var/www/directory with spaces/:
This works (php-fpm, DocumentRoot without spaces):
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/directory"
  <Directory "/var/www/directory">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
  </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>

This also works (no php-fpm, DocumentRoot has spaces -> php7.4 processes the script):
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/directory with spaces"
  <Directory "/var/www/directory with spaces">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

This fails (php-fpm, DocumentRoot has spaces):
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/directory with spaces"
  <Directory "/var/www/directory with spaces">
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
  </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>

Am I missing something?

Do you have very strong reason to use space in directory name?

Yes, we have an automated process for updating and syncronising those virtual hosts, so we cannot really alter their paths.

In this site we talk about "managing information technology systems in a business environment" so the argument above is not strong (for me)

Check this Q/A: https://serverfault.com/a/806213/293588

Ok thanks. But how would url-rewriting solve this issue, when apache stumbles upon the DocumentRoot path? (I edited the config to make the issue clearer.

I had the exact same problem today and over the last couple days with a local development project on my workstation.
I have a project directory with spaces in the name. The directory is like this:
"/home/chris/Development/Clients/My Clients Name/current"

I tried various google searches to find an answer and even used ChatGPT extensively to intelligently troubleshoot the problem.
In the end, I got around the problem by simply creating a symlink to my directory as follows;
cd /var/www  
ln -s /home/chris/Development/Clients/My\ Clients\ Name/current clientproject1


I then modified my virtual host DocumentRoot as follows:
DocumentRoot /var/www/clientproject1

Apache uses the "no-space" symlink to access the files and it worked just fine, if a bit klugy. Hope this helps!

This workaround solved it for me, thanks! I'm wondering if this new behaviour of apache is a bug or a feature(?)
